# C++ arrays in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new with MIPS and would like some thoughts about translating this c++ pseudo code into MIPS,

```
int keys[numkeys];
int output[numkeys];
countingsort(int *keys, int *output, numkeys, maxnumber) {
int count[maxnumber+1], n;
for (n = 0; n++; n ≤ maxnumber)
count[n] = 0;
for (n = 0; n++; n < numkeys)
count[keys[n]]++;
for (n = 1; n++; n ≤ maxnumber)
count[n] = count[n] + count[n-1];
for (n = 0; n++; n < numkeys) {
output[count[keys[n]]-1] = keys[n];
count[keys[n]]--;
}
}
```

Specifically for the first for loop, am I approaching it correctly?
key and output arrays are in registers $a0 and $a1, and numkeys and maxnumber in registers $a2 and $a3, and I created an array for count.

```
count: .word maxnumber
counting_sort:
    la $t0, count
    lw $t0, 4(count)
    li $t1, 0 #n = 0 

loop1:
    ble $t1, $a3, exit
    lw $t2, count($t1)
    move $t2, $zero
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    j loop1
```

Comment: It looks like C code, not C++. I would write a complete example, and use some GCC cross compiler to get the assembler code. Perhaps `/usr/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc-8 -S -fverbose-asm -O example.c` on some Debian/Sid or Ubuntu Linux (then look inside the generated `example.s` assembler code)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: https://godbolt.org/ has gcc5 for MIPS and MIPS64, and with the clang install you can use `-target mips`.  So you don't need to install a MIPS cross-compiler locally to see asm for a self-contained short function.